# How can I re-enable some of Tor browser's features? (like saved form & password entries)

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

The website I frequent blocks tor exit nodes so I use a different way to obtain a unique IP address outside the tor network, so I can't use the tor network for that site. I do need to use tor browser instead of firefox however, due to the built-in anonymity enhancements though.

However there are a few things I would like the tor browser to allow me to do:

1. when I disable my proxy port, I get the following message popup that I would like to disable (is it possible to disable this check?):

   > torbutton cannot safely give you a new identity. it does not have access to the Tor Control Port. are you running Tor Browswer Bundle"
2. is there a way to get tor browser to save form history & passwords the way firefox does?
3. is there a way to set the screensize & position that tor browser uses when I click the button to create a new identity?

Comment: I had the same needs as you and i found that Brave Browser is better than Tor Browser. The only thing that's annoying for the moment is that one cannot start automatically in Tor mode. One must use the argument --tor when opening the .app but then it is not possible to keep the shortcut in the dock to replace the Brave Browser shortcut: you can create such a shortcut, but it then spawns an additional Brave Browser dock icon upon launch. MacOS has so many poor design choices -it's disheartening how system programmers can make such choices and refuse communicating with users. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes if you also install the tor configuration package - if you ar using linux just go to the add/remove software api and search for tor. otherwise go to https://github.com/micahflee/torbrowser-launcher and https://www.torproject.org/ and make sure you have installed the Tor brwoser launch settings.
2. No
3. I dont know that - in theory you could try to fuck around the application it self and set some new defaults

Answer (score 0):

Tor browser is a Firefox specially tweaked in a source code to be what it is. If you need the features you're asking about - use a virtual machine routed through Tor **totally** and deploy a regular Firefox there - it will be the solution you're looking for.

Comment: This does not make much sense to me. 1 Why until a few months ago could we save logins ? 2 Why is there still a (now non functional) configuration page for logins ? 3 Why prevent users from enabling saving logins when they want to ? We don't want to impose our choice to others (contrary to some), we just want the possibility to save logins. It's a hassle to reenter logins every time, if i could use Safari instead of Tor Browser i would but Safari does not provide Tor routing and cannot bypass illegal censorship here.  That's all i want, Tor routing, and all usual features of a browser.

Comment: Also, leaving the feature visible with leaving any indication that the feature is non functional is at the very least a bug, and actually perverse.

Comment: it's not a bug, it's a work in progress. And - I agree - it looks odd. If you need normal browsing just secured by Tor - try to do as I recommended. You don't have to use Safari - use VirtualBox with a Linux guest routed through Tor and choose whatever browser you wish to use

Comment: Thank you Alexey, eventually i was helped by someone on the Tor Browser help site: https://forum.torproject.net/t/how-to-re-enable-login-saving-on-tor-browser-desktop/7926/3 . So i am now satisfied with how my installation behaves. But it took me a while; if it's not a bug then it was just as annoying. :)

Answer (score 0):

For your point 2 you can follow the instructions found in [this page](https://forum.torproject.net/t/how-to-re-enable-login-saving-on-tor-browser-desktop/7926/3). Depending on your version of Tor Browser and OS you will have to check in the page about:config (to be entered as address) whether *signon.autofillForms.http* is set to **true** and in the preferences whether a master password is set, and enable history and disable *Always use private browsing mode* in the security preferences.